# Redirect multiple google doc links into a single link

Tags: google-drive-api, share, google-docs

I have several of the same document, each shared with a different person. Is it possible to create a new document, and redirect all other links to the new document's link, so that I only have to update one doc for everyone to see the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hack, but replace each of the old documents with new versions (to keep the same Google link) consisting of simple text files with the standard Windows url content:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://google.com/link/to/common/doc
```

Then rename the file, adding the suffix .url
The old links won't go straight to the new document, but at least the user will get a webpage that redirects them to it by clicking "Apps on your computer: Internet Browser" or clicking download and then on the downloaded link.  Not pretty, but better than [nothing](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/158505810/setting-up-a-redirect-on-a-google-drive?hl=en).